# При запуске php artisan db:seed выбивает ошибку

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, artisan

php artisan migrate - команда проходит успешно,

далее

Запускаю   php artisan db:seed

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

InvalidArgumentException  : Cannot write to directory "/var/www/Marketor/storage/app\public\products"

at /var/www/Marketor/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php:69
    65|     {
    66|         $dir = is_null($dir) ? sys_get_temp_dir() : $dir; // GNU/Linux / OS X / Windows compatible
    67|         // Validate directory path
    68|         if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) {

> 69|             throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot write to directory "%s"', $dir));
>       70|         }
>       71|
>       72|         // Generate a random filename. Use the server address so that a file
>       73|         // generated at the same time on a different server won't have a collision.

Exception trace:

1   Faker\Provider\Image::image("/var/www/Marketor/storage/app\public\products")
      /var/www/Marketor/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:222

2   call_user_func_array()
      /var/www/Marketor/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:222

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Проверьте наличие директории `public/products`. Если её нет, то создайте.

**2** Воспользуйтесь хелпером `public_path()` для точного указания пути.

```
// Берем изображение по адресу http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/
// Сохраняем в public/products

$faker->image(public_path('products'), 640, 480, 'nature');
```

**3** Подробнее о методе [image()](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderimage)

Comment: папка сушествует конечно, права www-data прописаны,                                                              $faker->image(public_path('products'), 640, 480, 'nature'); -----  с этим что делать? подскажите?

Comment: Смотрите папку `database\seeds`, ищите файл, который отвечает за заполнение фейковыми данными (ProductSeeder).

Comment: спасибо помог. я разобрался. ) было причина в том что стояли обратные слеши  $newImage = 'products/'. $faker->image(storage_path('app\public\products'),256,256, null, false);  - -так было . так стало $newImage = 'products/'. $faker->image(storage_path('app/public/products'),256,256, null, false);  далее все без проблем зашло